# Preserving customizations when upgrading to Mathematica 10.3

Tags: version-10, installation

I currently have *Mathematica* 10.2.  If I upgrade to the just released 10.3, will I lose the modifications I've done to keyeventranslations.tr?  I'm not sure if *Mathematica* overwrites these files. What about other changes I've made to the system?  For insurance, is there a way to keep my old version of *Mathematica* with all modifications intact?

Comment: Why not back up your customized files, just to be sure?

Comment: I can do this... expect I'm not sure about the options In the Options Inspector.  I would like to keep them.    I know they are located in $UserBaseDirectory in the file "/FrontEnd/init.m" at the end of the large file, but seems like a messy way to backup these settings.  If I backup the whole file than I may lose something new in the 10.3 version.

Comment: I didn't loose any Options Inspector setting, that were saved in `$UserBaseDirectory`. However, I'd to re-modify *KeyEventTranslations.tr* and such, as these were installed in a new `$InstallationDirectory`.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!!!  I was hesitant.

Comment: yes you will lose them

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Its a good idea to stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer, better approaches may come later improving over a previous reply and experienced users may point to caveats. Therefore, new users may **wait 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and a bit more before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information)

Answer (score 9):

I always keep the previous version of *Mathematica* available when I upgrade. To have two independent version available, I advise checking **Preferences -> System -> Create and maintain version specific front end preferences** in your current version of *Mathematica* ***before*** you install the upgrade. After doing this, preferences will be maintained separately for each installed version. They are stored in ~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd in a _init.m file. You can (and probably will want to) replace the newly created 10.3_init.m file with a copy of your 10.2_init.m to restore your old preferences.

Comment: In Windows machines, this files are stored in `~\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\FrontEnd`

Answer (score 6):

Typically user-edited things in `$UserBaseDirectory` will not be changed on upgrade, in general.  However, everything in `$InstallationDirectory` will be reset to the default state.  If you modified that file in `$InstallationDirectory`, all modifications will be lost.

Regarding settings in the Options Inspector:  If you use version-specific front end settings (*Preferences* -> *System* -> *Create and maintain version specific front end preferences* is checked) then the settings will be lost, or rather: new settings will be created for the new version without touching the old version's settings.  Version-specific front end settings are not the default behaviour, so this won't be the case unless you changed it manually.  It only makes sense to use this setting if you have multiple versions installed.

Comment: Thank you!  This helps me a lot.